# Time convert from a file and compare to the current time

Tags: c, file, time

I've asked something close to this before, but as it seems, the time I get from the file does not convert to the same type of time you get from localtime() and time().

Exactly what I want is:

I have a txt file with the following information

**order.txt**

> file1.txt;5;15:40
>
> file2.txt;7;15:41
>
> file1.txt;10;16:00

My objective is to get the time in **hour:min** (15:40) and then, if it's the same as the **currentTime**, then I show the **file1.txt** content. Otherwise, if the **currentTime** is lower than the **hour:min** time (15:40), it waits untill it's **15:40** and shows the **file1.txt** content. If the **currentTime** is higher, then it ignores the first one and goes to the next one.

So for example, if the **current time** is **15:39**, it will wait **1 minute** and then show the **file1.txt** content.
If the **current Time** is **15:40**, it shows the file1.txt content without waiting.
If the **current Time** is **15:41**, it just goes to the next one (**file2.txt**) and checks again.

**Used variables**

```
FILE* orderFile;
FILE* contentFile;
FILE* defaultFile; (This will be used when this code works)
char fileName[50];
char textContent[5000];
int seconds;
int hour, min;
int diff_time;
char timeValue[50];
time_t current;
```

**Includes**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

***So for that I've tried the following code:***

```
orderFile = fopen("order.txt","r");
defaultFile = fopen("default.txt","r");

while(fscanf(orderFile," %49[^;];%d; %49[^\n]",fileName,&seconds,timeValue)
{

  sscanf(timeValue,"%d:%d",&hour,&min);

  contentFile = fopen(fileName,"r");
            
  if(contentFile != NULL)
  {
     fseek (contentFile, 0, SEEK_END);
     size = ftell(contentFile);
     rewind(contentFile);
                    
     if(size == 0)
     {
       printf("\nEmpty file. (Scanned file: %s)\n", fileName);
       fclose(contentFile);
     }
     else
     {
                    
         time_t now;
                        time(&now);

                        struct tm file_time_tm;
                        file_time_tm = *localtime(&now);
                        file_time_tm.tm_hour = hour;
                        file_time_tm.tm_min = min;
                        file_time_tm.tm_sec = 0;
                        file_time_tm.tm_isdst = -1;
                        time_t fileTime = mktime(&file_time_tm);

                        double diff_time = difftime(fileTime, now);
                        
                        if(diff_time == 0) 
                        {
                            while(fscanf(contentFile,"%[^\t]",textContent) == 1)
                            {
                                printf("%s\n", textContent);
                            }
                            sleep(seconds);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(diff_time > 0)
                            {
                                while(fscanf(defaultFile,"%[^\t]",defaultContent) == 1)
                                {
                                    printf("%s\n", defaultContent);
                                }
                                sleep(diff_time);
                                
                                while(fscanf(contentFile,"%[^\t]",textContent) == 1)
                                {
                                    printf("%s\n", textContent);
                                }
                                sleep(seconds);
                            }
                        }
                    
            fclose(defaultFile);      
            fclose(contentFile);
     }
   }
   else
   {
     if(contentFile == NULL)
     {
       printf("\nFile does not exist. (Scanned file: %s)\n", fileName);
       fclose(contentFile);
     }
   }
}

fclose(orderFile);
printf("\n");
```

So thanks to chux it is quite working now, yet not fully working.

If I have the following:

**Current Time:** 15:00

**order.txt**

> file1.txt;5;15:01
>
> file2.txt;6;15:02
>
> file3.txt;3;15:03

When I run the program, the following will occur:

> DEFAULT MESSAGE **(text inside default.txt)**
>
> WAITS **DIFF_TIME** (CORRECTLY DONE)
>
> SHOWS CONTENT FROM THE **file1.txt**
>
> WAITS **5 SECONDS**
>
> *X - SHOWS CONTENT FROM THE **file2.txt*** **(This is wrong, it should check again and if the time is 15:02 it will show, not 15:01. Which I assume it's because it is still reading as 15:01 on the timeValue and not 15:02, any idea why?)**
>
> WAITS UNTILL IT'S **15:02** **(wrong)**
>
> SHOWS **file3.txt (wrong)**
>
> WAITS UNTILL IT'S **15:03**
>
> ENDS **(wrong as it should not end after waiting, it should end when file3.txt shows and waits for 3 seconds)**

Output I need:

> DEFAULT MESSAGE
>
> ***waits diff_time***
>
> file1.txt content
>
> ***waits 5 seconds***
>
> DEFAULT MESSAGE
>
> ***waits diff_time***
>
> file2.txt content
>
> ***waits 7 seconds***
>
> DEFAULT MESSAGE
>
> ***waits diff_time***
>
> file3.txt content
>
> ***waits 3 seconds***
>
> ENDS

It also does not work well if I have two files with the same time, such as this:

**order.txt**

> file1.txt;5;15:01
>
> file2.txt;6;15:01
>
> file3.txt;3;15:02

It breaks it aswell.
Any idea of how to do this correctly?

Comment: If you enable warnings, you will see that you pass the wrong arguments to `difftime`. It expects two `time_t` values, but you pass one char buffer and a pointer to `struct tm`. You compare apples with oranges - using a function designed for comparing pineapples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented above by @M Oehm, it is apparent the compiler warnings are not fully enabled.  Suggest enabling them - it will save you time.

A problem lies in the time compare and subtraction.

```
// Troublesome code
if(currentTime->tm_hour < hour && currentTime->tm_min < min) {
  diff_time = difftime(currentTime,timeValue);
  printf("%d - Or this?\n", diff_time);
  sleep(diff_time);
}
```

1. The comparison is curious.  Usually with such a comparison would be in the form

   ```
   if (h1 < h2 || (h1 == h2 && m1 < m2))
   ```
2. `difftime` takes 2 `time_t` paramters, not `char timeValue[50]` and a `struct tm`.
3. The values passed to `double difftime(time_t time1, time_t time0)` appear backwards.  The result it `time1 - time0`.

Recommend instead

```
    int current_hm = currentTime->tm_hour * 60 + currentTime->tm_min;
    int file_hm = hour * 60 + min;

    if (current_hm < file_hm) {
      unsigned diff_time = (file_hm - current_hm)*60u;
      printf("%u - Or this?\n", diff_time);
      sleep(diff_time);
    }
```

---

[Edit]
Simplified approach.

```
    time_t now;
    time(&now);

    struct tm file_time_tm;
    file_time_tm = *localtime(&now);
    file_time_tm.tm_hour = hour;  // from file
    file_time_tm.tm_min = min; // from file
    file_time_tm.tm_sec = 0;
    file_time_tm.tm_isdst = -1;
    time_t filetime = mktime(&file_time_tm);

    double diff = difftime(filetime, now);  // filetime - now
    if (diff > 0) {
      sleep((unsigned) diff);
    }
```

Comment: That quite works, yet for some reason it only shows one of the files. 
(I'll edit my code so you can see how it is now). I took one of the whiles as there was one already with the same content. Also, any idea of how would be the if(current_hm > file_hm)? And, how can I know the seconds of the current time? Because if it's 14:41:41 and I need to show it at 14:41, it waits 60 seconds and not 19.

Comment: @Ran  `currentTime->tm_sec`

Comment: I did that, on the current_hm, right? But when the current_hm < file_hm it does nothing. And it shows th current_hm being bigger than file_hm. Should I do something to say file_hm has 0 seconds?

Comment: now I'm quite confused, should I delete the current_hm and file_hm and use the second one instead? also what is isdst? and mktime? and where should I use the if(diff > 0)? Is it possible you could update using my code? (the listing is inside the else). I'm new with this type of code

Comment: @Ran Yes recommend 2nd method.  Use `if(diff > 0)` to if `sleep()` should occur.  I could update your code, and provide a solution that would compiler without any work on your part, but then you would still be " new with this type of code".  Hopefully there is enough here so the new approach can readily be integrated into your work.

Comment: Its mostly because this is for a school work that I should do a presentation and we did not fully knew about this. We knew nothing about time as we did not learn it, and without this I cannot do the rest. I'll update my code with your second, may you say me if it's there and that how you mean? Also, can you check if you know why the while(fscanf(orderFile)) (first one) only does once? Thank you. Sorry for bothering aswell.

Comment: Also what's the file_time = localtime? I thought it would be currentTime I have but it doesn't work, and do not see it declared there...

Comment: `" %49[^;];%d; %49[^\t]"` has short comings, to much to go into now.  Try `" %49[^;];%d; %49[^\n]"`  (\t --> \n)

Comment: Answer updates with `file_time_tm = *localtime(&now);`.  BTW: It is not recommend to significantly change your post.  Better to _append_ changes.  GTG.

Comment: Oh sorry about it, didn't know. Also, I do not get it, will file_time_tm have both current and file times? Or only the now will have? (You can answer when you come back, thank you very much for your help)

Comment: Edited my code, when you come back if you can help me out I would appreciate. Otherwise will probably have to abandon the idea of doing it with hours, otherwise I'll not be able to finish it. Appreciate.

Comment: remade the code and it's working, yet if two files have 15:01, it will only list one and the second will show an error, which I'll probably have to change the 15:01 inside order.txt to 15:01:seconds. Unless there is another way to do it with something such as file_name_tm.tm_sec != 60-file_name_tm.tm_sec

Answer (score 1):

Chux's suggestion to do your comparisons with your own integer that represents the minutes after midnight is probably easier in your case, but if you want to use the standard time mechanisms, you can do it.

But first, keep in mind that there are two time representations, `time_t`, which is a "numerical" time that stores the seconds after the epoch and `struct tm`, which is the human-readable time that breaks a time down to years, months, days and so on.

With [`strptime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html), you can scan a string accoding to a format specification. It is the `scanf` for `struct tm`. This function does not initialise fields that are not specified, so that you can assign the current time with [`localtime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html) and then overwrite only the hour and minute fields.

[`mktime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktime.3.html) converts a `struct tm` to a `time_t`, which you can pass to difftime.

The following code snipped shows how such a comparison might work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    char stamp[] = "12:53";
    char *p;
    struct tm now;
    time_t t = time(NULL);

    now = *localtime(&t);
    p = strptime(stamp, "%H:%M", &now);

    if (p == NULL || *p != '\0') {
        printf("Illegal date.\n");
    } else {
        char buf[20];
        double dsec;
        int dmin;

        strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M\n", &now);
        puts(buf);

        dsec = difftime(t, mktime(&now));
        printf("Diff: %g sec\n", dsec);

        dmin = (int) dsec / 60;
        printf("Diff: %d min\n", dmin);
    }

    return 0;
}
```